# Why is the entry point address of a 64 bit portable executable only 32 bits?

Tags: winapi, linker, binaryfiles, portable-executable

According to the [definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) of `_IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` and `_IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64`, the `AddressOfEntryPoint` is a 32 bit `DWORD` for both PE32 and PE64 file formats.

Why is the `AddressOfEntryPoint` for a PE64 file only 32 bits?  Shouldn't it be 64 bits to cover the entire virtual address space?

Comment: Sections cannot be larger than 4 GB, a fundamental OS restriction.  So 32-bits is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation to which you link says:

> A pointer to the entry point function, relative to the image base address.

Being **relative** to the base address, this means that the image can be located anywhere in the address space.

This does indirectly imply that the entry point cannot have an offset from the base address of more than 4GB, but that is no limitation. A PE image cannot be larger than 4GB in size for other reasons. For instance, `SizeOfImage` is a `DWORD` which implies a limit on image size of 4GB.